# String check null or empty before assigning

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
string TEST1 = "abc def"

classA.detailList= (from tbl1 in ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
where tbl1["column1"] = 'aaaa'
select new classdetail(){
Var A = ToString().Substring(0, tbl1["Vehicle_Make_Model"].ToString    ().IndexOf(' ')).Trim()
Var B = ToString().Substring(tbl1["Vehicle_Make_Model"].ToString().IndexOf(' ') + 1).Trim()
```

}).ToList();
It works fine if i have string as TEST1 but how to handle if

```
TEST1="abc"
```

want to check whether second part is exists after space or not?

Please help me here

Comment: Have you tried splitting it on spaces and checking that it has two elements and element 2 is not `IsNullOrWhitespace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
      string[] outputParts = TEST1.Trim().Split(' ');

        if (outputParts.Length == 2)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: If Conditional statement is not allowed inside 
classA.detailList= (from tbl1 in ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
                              where tbl1["column1"] = 'aaaa'
                               select new classdetail(){
                                       }

Comment: @user1893874 your code is a little bit confusing for me, you defined TEST1, but where did you used it? why don't you wrap your query with if? would you mind explain your code more? so i can help you more.

Comment: Var A = ToString().Substring(0, TEST1.IndexOf(' ')).Trim()
Var B = ToString().Substring(TEST1.IndexOf(' ') + 1).Trim()

what i want is , to get first and last word in one line, without using split or IF condition.

for ex: TEST1 = 'abc def' then my code works fine

If i get only one value in TEST1 as 'abc'. code fails

Comment: @user1893874 Does it need to be in 1 line? Why can't you use an IF statement or a Split ?

Comment: @user1893874 if you don't wanna use split and if, you can use contains(" ")? : ,as this: var A = tbl1["Vehicle_Make_Model"].ToString.Contains(" ") ? ToString().Substring(0, tbl1["Vehicle_Make_Model"].ToString.IndexOf(' ')).Trim() : "//do what you want when string is only one part"; this will check if your string has space between, get first part, else (after :) write what you desire when string is only one part.